# Conditional modification of a csv cell using shell script

Tags: shell, csv

I've a csv file that looks like below

```
Name, Age, Status
John, 24, Online
Allan, 35, Offline
Steve, 40, Offline
```

Using shell script, I need to implement something like this

```
if (name == "Allan"), set Status="Online"
```

So the csv has to look like

```
Name, Age, Status
John, 24, Online
Allan, 35, **Online**
Steve, 40, Offline
```

I'm fairly new to shell, can someone please help?

Comment: If any of the following answer helped you in your goal please accept/upvote the answer for closure by ticking right sign besides the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F, -v OFS=,  '{split($5,a," ");if(a[2]=="Allan")gsub(/Offline/,"Online",$7)}1' inputfile
```

Explanation: If the keyword `"Allan"` is found in Fifth Column's second half then replace `Offline` to `Online` in seventh Column.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
awk 'BEGIN {OFS=FS=","} {if ($1=="Allan")sub($3,"Online"); print}' file
```